# Voltage dividers value signification

Tags: voltage-divider

Which is the difference between doing a voltage dividers from 5V to 3.3V with 10k and 20k resistors vs 4.7k and 2.4k?

It s easier to use the first option.

Comment: Other than that they aren't exactly the same ratio, "stiffness" when faced with load impedance (which itself becomes part of the effective divider), and the power wasted.  What are you doing with the divided voltage?  How fast does the voltage applied to the divider change, if it even changes at all?  Does the load ever change?

Comment: I need to connect the MCP3008 DOUT (Serial data) to the Raspberry Pi GPIO and I need to get 3.3V from 5V.

Comment: The smaller values sound like the better choice especially at higher baud rates, but the larger *might* still work.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually easier to do it using resistors you have. If you do it with resistors you don't have, it will take an extra day or so for them to arrive.

As you have correctly noticed, any two resistors should have the correct ratio for the voltage division. However ...

The smallest resistor \$R_{min}\$you can use is governed by
a) the driving current available at the source

The largest resistors \$R_{max}\$you can use are governed by
a) the resistive load you have to drive
b) and how fast you have to drive changes through any stray capacity it has

If you are lucky, then \$R_{min}\$>\$R_{min}\$, and there are some solutions available. This is usually the case with op-amps and CMOS gates in all combinations. This sometimes isn't the case with very weak sources, or heavy loads, and then you have to use something other than a voltage divider.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, a voltage divider is made with a load. The value of that load will greatly impact the choice of the resistor value. The second thing to think about is the current you want to use for that voltage devider.

Most of the time, IC's input are consider as infinite load. That mean you can use the value of resistor you want. An infinite resistor in parallel is consider as a dead branch (due to the very low amount of current passing through)

Comment: An IC input is *not* an infinite load, especially at higher frequencies where its capacitance can become noticeable.  And that's for ordinary inputs.  Things like typically MCU ADC inputs can have surprisingly low impedance (be quite "heavy" loads) in some modes of operation.